# Move Google Maps logo when using in a iPhone app

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I wonder if it's possible to move the Google logo that shows at the bottom left corner of every MKMapView object that is used in a iPhone app.

I don't want to make it disappear, just move it, for example, to the bottom right corner. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no direct API to manipulate the logo, you can still implement a workaround.
The Google logo is the second view in the map view's collection of child views. Here is pseudocode in your `MapViewController` class:

```
// Get logo image view   
UIImageView* imageView = [self.mapView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
// Get the actual image
UIImage* googleLogo = [imageView image];
// Declare your own image view (googleMapsLogo) to host the logo
// and put it onto map view at the desired position
// Assign to Google logo image to it
self.googleMapsLogo.image = googleLogo;
// Hide the original Google logo
imageView.hidden = YES;
```

If you need to dynamically position the logo, you can do so by changing `googleMapsLogo.center` property. Alternatively, you can try to re-position the original logo's image view.

Comment: I imagine that (hiding the logo) would be against the ToS.

Comment: You are not hiding the logo per se. I described a workaround to display the logo in a different place. Of course, if you modify the logo's size or put it in a completely different spot on the map, you may get rejected. However, you may find yourself in a situation when you want, for example, to display a half transparent view at the bottom of the map. The logo would be obscured by your view in this case and your app will be rejected by Apple for sure. I had experience. In this case my workaround works fine. Tested.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with the available APIs.